# Intercept all Form / POST Events

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'd  like to intercept all Form Actions / POST events send to the server to do data validation once, instead each time per page in sveltekit.

I figured the best place might be `hooks.server`, but it only exposes the `handle` function, not the `actions: Actions` that is needed for using `invalid( ... )` for returning data validation.

Is there a way to return `invalid(...)` in `hooks.server` or access `actions:`, or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing particularly special about `invalid`. It ultimately causes a JSON response of the form:

```js
{
  type: 'invalid',
  status: number, // HTTP code
  data: any, // Object that will be passed to `form` property of page
}
```

So you can use the `handle` hook to do validation, e.g.

```js
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    if (event.request.method == 'POST') {
        const errorInfo = await validate(event.request);

        if (errorInfo) {
            return json({
                type: 'invalid',
                status: errorInfo.status,
                data: errorInfo.data,
            }, { status: errorInfo.status });
        }
    }

    return await resolve(event);
}

async function validate(r: Request) {
    // `clone()` so the rest of the code that might also
    // try to read the request should not be affected
    const data = await r.clone().formData();

    // Validation logic here
}
```